# rails cancancan gem how to limit permission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan

I want to use cancancan restrict the permission. For example: If I have a Task model. User only can see not assigned tasks, cannot see assigned tasks.

**Ability model:**

```
can :manage, Task, :user_id => false
```

But right now, user cannot see all the tasks. What is wrong? Hope anyone can help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
can :manage, Task do |task|
 task.user_id == nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks for help! why need to add `or false`?

Comment: Don't need to add or false